# Custom inner template (view) for dialogs / modals?

Tags: dialog, durandal, durandal-2.0

I have the following:

```
    app.showMessage('template', book.title(), [save, cancel]).then(function(result) {
        if (result == save) {
            alert('saved');
        } else if (result == cancel) {
            alert('canceled');
        }
    });
```

This is working great, but I'd like to replace `'template'` with the path of a view that will get bound to the current viewmodel (a form for add/edit object).  Is there any mechanism in place to achieve this?

I've done this:

```
  dialog.MessageBox.setViewUrl('/App/views/templates/editBook.html');
```

Which works, but all of the chrome and dialog goodness is lost - it replaces the entire dialog template, not just the inner template.

EDIT:

I now have a dedicated view/viewmodel pair and I'm using this:

```
    vm.editBook = function (book) {
        dialog.show('viewmodels/editBook', book);
    };
```

With my editBook.js:

```
  define(function () {
    var vm = {};

    vm.book= ko.observable();

    vm.cancel = function () {
        alert('should cancel');
    };

    vm.save = function() {
    };

    vm.activate = function(book) {
        vm.book(book);
    };

    return vm;

});
```

my view:

```
<div data-view="plugins/messageBox" class="messageBox" data-bind="with: book">,
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 data-bind="text: title"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="message" data-bind="text: title"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">

        <button data-bind="click: $parent.cancel">cancel</button>

        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But then how do I close the dialog from the view?  I tried passing the dialog object to the vm to call `dialog.close` but this doesn't seem to work.

Update again:  By requiring the `dialog` plugin and calling dialog.close(vm), durandal knows how to select and close the right dialog:

```
vm.cancel = function () {
    //alert('should cancel');
    dialog.close(vm);
};
```

So I think I'm all set... but any confirmation would be cool from the pros out there.

Comment: Look at `dialog.show(viewModel, ..)`, ref. [dialog.js](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/master/src/plugins/js/dialog.js)

Comment: Thanks @user2864740, I've seen that.  Doesn't seem to handle the case where I want to keep the chrome and provide a custom inner html template though.

Comment: @user2864740 - just pushed it a bit further with that function.  Any idea how I can close the dialog from within a child viewmodel?  Code updated.

Comment: You require "durandal/dialog" in you script for your custom dialog, then you use "dialog.close()" from within your model to close the modal dialog.

You can also pass "activationData" to your viewmodel using `app.showDialog('path/to/view', { name: 'something' })` and the get the object in the activate function in the viewmodel.